# how to achieve scrollable nav-container like in material.angular.io website?

Tags: html, css, angular-material2

https://material.angular.io/components

I cant seem to replicate their setup

Basically they have an md-toolbar
below the toolbar is md-sidenav-container

Their sidenav-container's height seem to be scrollable and doesn't overflow beyond the height of the browser/device

```
//from my app.component.html or my root component
//the index.html is generated by angular cli and remained untouched
//no additional css applied
<link rel="stylesheet" [href]="sanitizedTheme">

<div class="main-spinner" *ngIf="usrsvc.hasPendingTask">
    <md-spinner color="accent"></md-spinner>
</div>
<md-toolbar id="main-toolbar" color="primary">
    <button md-icon-button (click)="sidenav.toggle()"> <md-icon>menu</md-icon> </button> navaLine
    <span class="spacer"></span>
    <md-select placeholder="Theme" [(ngModel)]="themeModel" (change)="getSanitizedTheme()" >
        <md-option value="deeppurple-amber" >
            DEEPPURPLE-AMBER
        </md-option>
        <md-option value="indigo-pink" >
            INDIGO-PINK
        </md-option>
        <md-option value="pink-bluegrey" >
            PINK-BLUEGRAY
        </md-option>
        <md-option value="purple-green" >
            PURPLE-GREEN
        </md-option>
    </md-select>
</md-toolbar>
<md-sidenav-container>
    <md-sidenav #sidenav>
        <md-list>
            <md-list-item>
                <button md-button (click)="usrsvc.navigate('/'); sidenav.close()"> <md-icon>home</md-icon> Home</button>
            </md-list-item>
        </md-list>
    </md-sidenav>

    <div class="main">
        <router-outlet></router-outlet>
    </div>

</md-sidenav-container>
```

this is my temporary approach for now

```
calcHeight() {
    var toolbarHeight = document.getElementById('main-toolbar').clientHeight;
    this.mainDivMaxHeight = (window.innerHeight - toolbarHeight).toString() + "px";
}
ngAfterViewInit() {
    window.onresize = () => {
        this.calcHeight();
    };
}
```

Comment: I added a general solution for given problem, if you would like something more specific to your case, please provide a link to your page or fiddle.

Answer (score 1):

You have to set the height of the container and allow overflow-y as auto.

```
#nav_wrapper {
  height: 100vh;
  overflow-y: auto;
}
```

Additionally, you could make its position fixed if you expect rest of page to be higher than the viewport.

Comment: using something like 100vh will just extend the page. by using this. the document height becomes the toolbarheight+the nav_wrapper height. Solution is only good if the toolbar has a static height.

Comment: Do you have the specific code so I could see whats going on?

Comment: On the angular page, they have nav height set to 100% which solves the problem with toolbar height but the rest page must be styled in the way that the body never goes higher than viewport so the content component on the right must have set its own scroller too. You can see it well when you choose e.g. Slider from the nav.